# What is the difference between //*[local-name()='element'] and //*:element?

Tags: xpath

It seems that in some usecases the expression

```
//*[local-name()='element']
```

selects more than

```
//*:element
```

or, in other words, the first expression works on a more general level, while the second one seems to work more restrictive.

What could be the reason for this? It seems to be a namespace issue, but we could not figure it out yet.

Comment: can you provide sample XML that demonstrate the behavior described in this question? Both expressions means the same as far as I can see. Only the latter is not supported in XPath 1.0

Comment: This could already be the solution of the problem. Depending on the environment and on the various components, it might occur that somewhere XPath 1.0 is used. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [node test](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#node-tests) `*:element` is only valid in XPath 2.0. The spec says:

> A node test can also have the form *:NCName. In this case, the node test is true for any node of the principal node kind of the step axis whose local name matches the given NCName, regardless of its namespace or lack of a namespace.

So it's equivalent to `*[local-name()='element']`.